# Explicit solution for an inhomogeneous non-linear first-order ordinary differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Is there some non-linear function $f(y)$ for which an explicit particular solution to the differential equation

\begin{equation}
y'(x) + f(y(x)) = g(x)
\end{equation}

can be given for a general function $g(x)$.

Comment: $f(y)=gy$ then the DE is separable.

Comment: Since the linear case is rather trivial I specifically excluded it in the question. @MtGlasser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I guess I found an answer by trial and error. For $f(y) = \textrm{e}^{- a y}$ with some $a \in \mathbb{R}$ the equation is solved by

\begin{equation}
y(x) = \frac{1}{a} \, \ln\left( \left[ 1 + a \, g_3(x) \, \textrm{e}^{a g_1(x)} \right] \textrm{e}^{a y_0} - a \, g_2(x) \, \textrm{e}^{a g_1(x)} \right) \; ,
\end{equation}

for some $y_0$ at some $x_0$ and with

\begin{equation}
g_1(x) = \int_{x_0}^x \textrm{d}x^\prime \, g(x^\prime) \; ,
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
g_2(x) = \int_{x_0}^x \textrm{d}x^\prime \, \textrm{e}^{-a g_1(x^\prime)} \; ,
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
g_3(x) = \int_{x_0}^x \textrm{d}x^\prime \, \textrm{e}^{-a g_1(x^\prime)} \, g(x^\prime) \; ,
\end{equation}

assuming $g(x)$ is sufficiently regular so that the above expressions make sense. If anyone has more details on this solution or has another example for a $f(y)$ which allows for an explicit solution, I would be happy to hear about them.